# Pip installing cloned forked repositories for local and production use

Tags: python, github, pip, fork

I just forked a github repo I'm interested in customizing for my project. I cloned my fork so I have a local copy to work on but now how do I use this cloned copy for my project--maybe a `pip install <cloned local repo>` command I can use? And when I'm done how will this translate in my *requirements.txt* file when I move everything to production?

I know I can install using

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/user/repo.git@master
```

but I want to use the cloned copy on my computer if possible so I don't have to keep pushing any changes I make as I make them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

```
pip install 'git+file:///home/user/example/.git'
pip install 'git+file:///home/user/example/.git@master'
pip install 'git+file:///home/user/example/.git@0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
```

Comment: Thanks @iBug exactly what I'm looking for. So when I go to production how is the Pipfile entry supposed to look like when I direct it to my fork instead of the usual `original-package=*` line?

Comment: @enchance Use `git+https://` to point to your fork should suffice - keep in mind there's no version checking so the same version will be re-installed on every `pip install` run.